# can I reuse a CAAnimation instance by modifying it after adding it to a layer?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

This is interesting... I'd think that by doing this

```
CABasicAnimation* a = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    a.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.];
    a.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.];
    a.duration = .4;
    a.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    a.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CGFloat timeOffset = 0;
for(CALayer* layer in layers)
{
    a.beginTime = [someCommonSuperView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime()fromLayer:nil] + timeOffset;
    [layer addAnimation:a forKey:nil];
    timeOffset += .4;
}
```

I am actually always modifying the same CABasicAnimation's beginTime and just incrementing its reference count. So thatI wouldn't get a series of layers fading in one after the other but rather should be messing up the start time of all of them, possibly causing all of them to just show up at once at the time of the last one. But the above code actually seems to work in that the layers fade in sequentially.

So does it make sense to reuse the animation in this way? So as to not create a new instance of it on each pass?

Is addAnimation actually making a deep copy of the animation instead of increasing the reference count?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW14):

> `- (void)addAnimation:(CAAnimation *)anim forKey:(NSString *)key`
>
> Add an animation object to the receiver’s render tree for the specified key.
>
> Parameter `anim`:
>
> The animation to be added to the render tree. Note that the object is
>   copied by the render tree, not referenced. Any subsequent
>   modifications to the object will not be propagated into the render
>   tree.

So I'd say it's safe to reuse the same `CAAnimation` object.

Comment: Oh nice! and I feel so silly I just missed that it was right there all this time in the reference. Sorry for having you "look it up for me". It's interesting though that I've run into a few cases along the lines of my sample above where it seemed I was affecting other layers by modifying a single animation. But now it's clear that I was probably messing up something else (probably a group's property). Thanks!

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz You weren't imagining things - some `CAAnimation` types, like `CABasicAnimation`, can be updated after being added to the render tree though the docs say otherwise, making it undependable behavior.

Comment: Thankfully, CAAnimation conforms to NSCopying, so we can easily copy it ourselves when adding it to the target. Just to be sure. `target.add(animation.copy(), forKey: "custom.animation.key")` 